# android show error when share content on another application

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

Android show fatal exception when run application in android nougat when sharing data to another application. It runs perfectly  below nougat.

Here is my code

```
  Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Student Details of " + currentDate);
  sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u1);
  sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
  startActivity(sendIntent);  // Gives error on this line
```

This Is the error shows.

```
04-08 18:31:38.371 18464-18464/manager.attendance.com E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: manager.attendance.com, PID: 18464
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=5, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {manager.attendance.com/manager.attendance.com.activity.MainActivity}: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Exported%20Data/Data-08-Apr-2017.csv exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4094)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4137)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1529)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                                                                     Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Exported%20Data/Data-08-Apr-2017.csv exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
                                                                        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1813)
                                                                        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2360)
                                                                        at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:832)
                                                                        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8957)
                                                                        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8942)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1583)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4228)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4187)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4515)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4483)
                                                                        at manager.attendance.com.activity.MainActivity.exportToCsvAndSend(MainActivity.java:171)
                                                                        at manager.attendance.com.activity.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:191)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38203793/115145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, 
getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

Instead of

```
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

It is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content)